# GitLab CI/CD host key verification failed

Tags: ssh, gitlab, pipeline, cicd

I'm trying to make a pipeline in GitLab, but the job throws an error "host key verification failed".

I already tried many ways to fix it, like providing the correct permissions to files etc.

Worth mentioning, that I checked if the known_hosts file exists and it does, also the ssh key isn't password protected.

Heres the pipeline code:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  tags: [docker-run]
  stage: build
  script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$LI_SSH_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -vT git@gitlab.li.lv
    - docker build -t li-php-image .
    - docker run li-php-image composer install
  only:
    - master

test:
  tags: [docker-run]
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker run li-php-image composer cs-check
  only:
    - master
```

The error occurs on the composer install part, when trying to install a module.